# Including a condition dynamically in sql(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as below

```
select --------
from table a
left outer join ....c
where 
(a.column='123') and (c.column='456')
```

I would like to

> include "(c.column='456')" only when (c.column='456') is not null

how do I do that in a single query ? or do I need to write two separate queries ?

I tried (a.column='123') and (c.column is null), did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
select --------
from table a
left outer join ....c
where 
((a.column='123') and (c.column='456'))
or c.column is not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the check for null and the value 456 in the same set of parenthesis:

```
select --------
from table a
left outer join ....c
where 
(a.column='123') and (c.column is not null and c.column='456')
```